# При нажатии на кнопку выдает процесс стопед

Tags: android

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temper);
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) 
        {
        case R.id.temper:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, addwork.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;        
         }
    }
});
```

совместил 2 проекта, в отдельности все работает, а вместе для перехода на addwork при нажатии на кнопку выдает процесс стопед
извиняюсь за очередной не понятный вопрос

```
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.arta/com.example.arta.addwork}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at com.example.arta.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:50)
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: MainActivity зарегистрирована в файле манифеста?

Comment: да зарегистрирован

Comment: Тогда показывайте logcat

Comment: я глуп :(( спасибо вам большое =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

тогда что это

> Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.arta/com.example.arta.addwork}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 05-21 14:16:38.583: E/AndroidRuntime(930): at

если активити зарегистрировано?